# select case in linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

How can I trasfrom the following sql statement into linq

```
 select  AdsProperties.AdsProID,
         AdsProperties.IsActive,
         AdsProperties.Name,
           case
                when AdsProperties.ControlType =1 then -- TextBox
                  'Textbox'
                when AdsProperties.ControlType =2 then -- DropDown
                  'Dropdown'
                when AdsProperties.ControlType =3 then -- ConboBox
                  'ComboBox'
                else -- RadioButton
                  'RadioButtont'
           end as ControlType   
   from CLF.utblCLFAdsPropertiesMaster as AdsProperties
```

I have tried this

```
var query = from AdsProperties in db.utblCLFAdsPropertiesMasters
            select new
            {
                AdsProperties.AdsProID,
                AdsProperties.Name,
                AdsProperties.IsActive,
                ControlType = AdsProperties.ControlType == 1 ? (int?)"TextBox" : null,
                ControlType = AdsProperties.ControlType == 2 ? (int?)"Dropdown" : null,
                ControlType = AdsProperties.ControlType == 3 ? (int?)"ComboBox" : null,                 
                ControlType = AdsProperties.ControlType == 4 ? (int?)"RadioButton" : null)
            };
            dt = query.CopyToDataTableExt();
```

but I am getting this error

```
`an anynomous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name`
```

I know that it may be easy and simple. However, being new in linq, I haven't the approrpiate experience to deal with it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a separate method for the switch statement and assign that to the ControlType property.e.g. `ControlType = GetControlType(AdsProperties.ControlType)`

Comment: Why not to use Enum to ControlType instead of int?

Comment: Magical strings are evil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare an array of strings as:

```
string[] controls = new string[] {"TextBox","Dropdown","ComboBox","RadioButton"};
```

Modify your query as mentioned below:

```
var query = from AdsProperties in db.utblCLFAdsPropertiesMasters
                    select new
                    {
                        AdsProperties.AdsProID,
                        AdsProperties.Name,
                        AdsProperties.IsActive,
                        ControlType = AdsProperties.ControlType < controls.Length ? controls[AdsProperties.ControlType-1] : null
                    };
        dt = query.CopyToDataTableExt();
```

Comment: Well, I don't think this is the most foolproof way to do it. What if another control type with index 999 gets added? Also, it is possible to have a different type for controlType, what if it's nullable? or even changed to a string value. I would consider this as a work around and not a solution as this is bound to fail if there are changes made in the system in future.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh: Thanks for suggestion. Can you please review my answer now?

Answer (score 2):

```
  var query = from AdsProperties in db.utblCLFAdsPropertiesMasters
                    select new
                    {
                        AdsProperties.AdsProID,
                        AdsProperties.Name,
                        AdsProperties.IsActive,
                         ControlType = (AdsProperties.ControlType == 1) ? "TextBox" :
                                       (AdsProperties.ControlType == 2) ? "Dropdown" :
                                       (AdsProperties.ControlType == 3) ? "ComboBox" : 
                                       (AdsProperties.ControlType == 4) ? "RadioButton" : ""
                    };
        dt = query.CopyToDataTableExt();
```

Comment: This is somewhat similar to what I posted. You beat me by 8 seconds. ;)

Comment: Yes I wonder that StackOver did not stop it, seems like major delays on servers or somewhere else...

Comment: Anyways, +1 for beating me in time. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code.

```
var query = from AdsProperties in db.utblCLFAdsPropertiesMasters
    select new
    {
        AdsProperties.AdsProID,
        AdsProperties.Name,
        AdsProperties.IsActive,
        ControlType = AdsProperties.ControlType == 1 ? "TextBox" : 
            (AdsProperties.ControlType == 2) ? "Dropdown" : 
            (AdsProperties.ControlType == 3) ? "ComboBox" : 
            (AdsProperties.ControlType == 4) ? "RadioButton" : 
            null)
    };
dt = query.CopyToDataTableExt();
```

Also, if you want to make it less messy, you can try to put your condition in another method and make a call like:

```
var query = from AdsProperties in db.utblCLFAdsPropertiesMasters
    select new
    {
        AdsProperties.AdsProID,
        AdsProperties.Name,
        AdsProperties.IsActive,
        ControlType = GetControlType(AdsProperties.ControlType)
    };
dt = query.CopyToDataTableExt();
```

And your GetControlType will be something like:

```
private string GetControlType(int controlIndexOrWhatever)
{
    switch(controlIndexOrWhatever)
    {
        case 1: return "TextBox";
        case 2: return "DropDown";
        case 3: return "ComboBox";
        case 4: return "RadioButton";
        default: return null;            
    }
}
```

But then again, it's not tested and doesn't work with LINQ to entities. I think it might work for LINQ to SQL. Don't mind syntax issues if any, just wrote the code without checking on VS.

Comment: dynamic typecast string to nullable int, please explain what do you expect?

Comment: My bad, just copied the OPs code. I am not sure what he meant doing that, but have provided somewhat a solution to the problem.

Comment: It could be fine enough with Linq-To-Objects, then do `AsEnumerable`, so `var query = from AdsProperties in db.utblCLFAdsPropertiesMasters.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
        AdsProperties.AdsProID,
        AdsProperties.Name,
        AdsProperties.IsActive,
        ControlType = GetControlType(AdsProperties.ControlType)
    };
dt = query.CopyToDataTableExt();`. Of course the select is then done in your application, not on the database server.

Comment: @Aron - Thanks. Thought so, but did not get a chance to test.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Thanks mate, will test this and make an update to the answer.